# Google Charts: Is it possible to have a table as the horizontal axis?

Tags: google-visualization

I need to display a chart where the horizontal axis is a kind of a table. I checked the Google Charts documentation as well as other links but could not find any help. Can you tell me whether something like that is possible in Google Charts? If yes, then how?

Below is the link to an image showing a similar kind of a thing.

https://i0.wp.com/criticaltosuccess.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/IMG-XL2010-Chart-w-Two-Rows-X-Axis-Labels-and-Lines-e1405615373977.png?resize=600%2C330

Comment: nothing that will do it for you, but you can draw a table chart underneath the line chart -- will take some customization to align everything

Comment: hmmm.. thank you. Will try that approach then.